# How to start a non existent Activity mentioned in Manifest?

Tags: android

I am attempting to develop a "Dynamic" Android application.

Dynamic in the sense that I have an activity listed in the manifest that is "built" at runtime.

I can build the required activity fine, however, when I attempt to start it my application fails with...

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.research.ps/com.research.Dynamic}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Didn't find class "com.research.Dynamic" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.research.ps-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.research.ps-1/lib/arm, 
/data/app/com.research.ps-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Is there an approach I can take to successfully instantiate an Android Activity at runtime?

Is there a way I can add a "temporary" or "shell" activity onto my application path? and then replace the "temporary" activity with my dynamic instance?

UPDATE

My Manifest XML contains this entry

```
<activity
  android:name=".Dynamic"
  android:label="@string/title_activity_dynamic"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

However, there is no Activity called "Dynamic" contained within my application.

I am using ByteBuddy to build my dynamic activity:-

```
  final Class<? extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity> dynamicType = new ByteBuddy(ClassFileVersion.JAVA_V8)
            .subclass(android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.class, IMITATE_SUPER_CLASS)
            .name("com.research.Dynamic")
            .make()
            .load(getClass().getClassLoader(), new AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.Wrapping(this.getDir("dexgen", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)))
            .getLoaded();

final Intent intent = new Intent(this, dynamicType);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: can you add some code ?! how are you initiating your activity for an example

Comment: Can you see me your some code of activity for understanding quetion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have managed to call a dynamically instantiated Activity and set the required layout content using ByteBuddy.

Heres how

```
final DynamicType.Unloaded<? extends AppCompatActivity> dynamicType = new ByteBuddy(ClassFileVersion.JAVA_V8)
        .subclass(AppCompatActivity.class)
        .name(CLASS_NAME)
        .method(named("onCreate").and(takesArguments(1)))
        .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(TargetActivity.class).andThen(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE))
        .make();

final Class<? extends AppCompatActivity> dynamicTypeClass = dynamicType.load(getClassLoader(), new AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.Injecting(this.getDir("dexgen", Context.MODE_PRIVATE))).getLoaded();

final Intent intent = new Intent(this, dynamicTypeClass);
startActivity(intent);
```

The method delegation class

```
public class TargetActivity {

    public static void intercept(Bundle savedInstanceState, @This AppCompatActivity thiz) {
        thiz.setContentView(R.layout.activity_fourth);
    }
}
```

Even though this gives the desired result it still has issues as the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` call is made after I have called `setContent` (I think).

Using the excellent ByteBuddy library is a much better approach IMHO than working with DEX manipulation.

Answer (score 12):

**Yes** you **CAN** start such an `Activity` (assuming you have a ***dummy*** manifest  `Activity` entry).
 If you don't like this technique, use **`Fragments`** (they don't need entries in the manifest).
 Alternatively use [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) like [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) et-al (cross platform too !).
[ByteBuddy](http://bytebuddy.net/#/) (kudos too @Rafael Winterhalter author of Byte Buddy) looks cool, maybe a learning curve involved. Why not download the [linked project](https://github.com/timrae/custom-class-loader) and try both techniques.
Here's how to `include` `ByteBuddy` in your Android Studio `Gradle` project (`build.gradle`):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25'
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25'
        compile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.9'
        compile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-android:1.7.9'
    }
}
```

> how I can "find" my dynamically instantiate class at runtime?

## External loading of DEX files (class byte code)

[See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175169/how-to-build-an-apk-and-separate-libraries-that-the-app-loads-dynamically/39278805#39278805) and follow the links for source code and tutorial (Apache Ant {`Eclipse` compatible, `build.xml`} and Android Studio `Gradle` examples `build.gradle` of the same code, you need some custom build steps which these project's provide).
Code snippet:

```
        // Internal storage where the DexClassLoader writes the optimized dex file to.
        final File optimizedDexOutputPath = getDir(SECONDARY_DEX_INTERNAL_DIR, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Initialize the class loader with the secondary dex file.
        DexClassLoader cl = new DexClassLoader(dexInternalStoragePath.getAbsolutePath(),
                                                optimizedDexOutputPath.getAbsolutePath(),
                                                null,
                                                getClassLoader());
        Class libProviderClazz = null;//variable libProviderClazz of type Class

        try {
            // Load the library class from the class loader.
            libProviderClazz = cl.loadClass(PROVIDER_CLASS);

            // Cast the return object to the library interface so that the
            // caller can directly invoke methods in the interface.

            // Alternatively, the caller can invoke methods through reflection,
            // which is more verbose and slow.
            LibraryInterface lib = (LibraryInterface) libProviderClazz.newInstance();

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Handle exception gracefully here.
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
```

> Q: How do I add an Activity, I cannot add it to the manifest ?
>   A: Use
>   Fragments, they don't need entries in the manifest.